# Using DryML views without hobo in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I am attempting to use dryml views for my rails project without using hobo. My version of ruby is 2.0.0 and the version of rails I am using is 4.2.3. I was following the instructions on this page: https://github.com/Hobo/hobo/blob/master/dryml/README

I attempted to follow them through but instead got this error when updating the bundler:

```
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "actionpack":
  In snapshot (Gemfile.lock):
    actionpack (= 4.2.3)

  In Gemfile:
    rails (= 4.2.3) x64-mingw32 depends on
      actionmailer (= 4.2.3) x64-mingw32 depends on
        actionpack (= 4.2.3) x64-mingw32

rails (= 4.2.3) x64-mingw32 depends on
  actionmailer (= 4.2.3) x64-mingw32 depends on
    actionpack (= 4.2.3) x64-mingw32

sass-rails (~> 5.0) x64-mingw32 depends on
  sprockets-rails (< 4.0, >= 2.0) x64-mingw32 depends on
    actionpack (>= 3.0) x64-mingw32

rails (= 4.2.3) x64-mingw32 depends on
  actionmailer (= 4.2.3) x64-mingw32 depends on
    actionpack (= 4.2.3) x64-mingw32

dryml (>= 0) x64-mingw32 depends on
  actionpack (< 3.0.0, >= 2.2.2) x64-mingw32

dryml (>= 0) x64-mingw32 depends on
  actionpack (< 3.0.0, >= 2.2.2) x64-mingw32
```

I am using Windows 8 if that makes any difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the [latest version of dryml](https://rubygems.org/gems/dryml/versions/2.1.1) locks you into Rails 4.0.x (see actionpack dependency). You won't be able to use it with Rails 4.2 unless you fork the gem and loosen the gemspec dependency yourself.

However it looks like there is already [an open issue on that project](https://github.com/Hobo/hobo/issues/138) about some issues with Rails 4.2 so you probably don't want to do that.  You could help out on that issue by making the needed fixes or helping test them after someone else does.

Comment: Thanks for information. I attempted to fork the gem and lossen the gem spec dependency. It didn't work out too well as you can imagine. I like the idea of of dropping to Rails 4.0.x though so I'll give that a shot. Thanks again!